# Troca de Mascara usando Jquery Mask Plugin?

Tags: jquery-mask-plugin

Estou criando um sistema Web e neste sistema existe o campo telefone, neste campo telefone, o usuário pode colocar um 0800 ou então um telefone convencional padrão DDD-Sufixo-Prefixo.

Atéai tudo bem, consegui criar com um `if`, só que ao digitar o segundo número ele muda a mascara se for do padrão escolhido, então no caso eu queria segurar o padrão somente para o primeiro caractere.

Segue abaixo o código que criei.

```
<input type="text" id="telefone" 
   name="escTelefone" 
   class="medio" 
   placeholder="(99)1111-1111" maxlength="13" />

<!--pattern="\([0-9]{2}\)[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}"-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#telefone").keypress(function (event) { 
        if(event.keyCode == 48 ) { 
            $("#telefone").mask("0000-000-0000"); 
        } else { 
            $("#telefone").mask("(00)0000-0000");
        }       
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Em vez de utilizar o evento **keypress**, você pode utilizar o evento **blur**:

> **Evento Blur**
>
> O evento blur é disparado quando um determinado elemento perde o foco,
>   o que pode ocorrer se o usuário pressionar TAB, por exemplo, sobre o
>   controle ou se clicar em outra região da página que também receba
>   foco.
>
> Fonte: [Linha de Código](http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/3549/como-tratar-eventos-de-formularios-com-jquery.aspx)

Verificar se o campo não está vazio e quais os primeiros dígitos que ele contém.

```js
$(document).on('blur', '#telefone', function(event) {
  var campo = $(this).val();
  // Verifica quais os primeiros dígitos informados.
  if (campo !== "" && campo.substring(0,2) === "08" || campo.substring(0,3) === "(08") {
    $("#telefone").mask("0000-000-0000");
  } else {
    $("#telefone").mask("(00) 0000-0000");
  }
  // console.log(campo.substring(0, 2));
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="telefone" name="escTelefone" class="medio" placeholder="(99)1111-1111" maxlength="13"  />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.11/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
```